# Training accuracy changes as lot

Tags: classification, convergence, conv-neural-network

A i am currently training a phoneme detector using a yes/no data set..

but the training accuracies seem a bit weird.. accuracies changes constantly..

[image]

Not quite sure How i should interpret..

Is it learning anythinG?
I mean it just the accuracy on the training set that is crazy while the validation set is "pretty" constant..

Comment: Your model is totally screwed. You'd expect your performance improve for more epochs. In fact, that didn't happen at all.

Comment: hmm... I know that there might be many reasons why it is doing so, but do you have any idea why?.. my dataset is pretty small @SmallChess, and I guess i have way more parameter versus data points...

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the learning rate to smaller?

Comment: using adam... so it should be handled by that...